# Variable SQL Table Name in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, combobox

I have a combobox full of values. I would like a SQL query that takes the selected combobox value as the name of the table to look up.

I have tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM [MachineNumber] WHERE ([MachineNumber] = @MachineNumber)
```

with a control parameter in the next line of

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ComboBox1" Name="MachineNumber"  
                      PropertyName="SelectedValue" />"
```

However this returns an error

> Must declare the scalar variable @MachineNumber

Isn't the control parameter declaring it when I choose a value from the combobox?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: The error is getting because you are trying to use a variable in your SQL Statement `@MachineNumber` that does not exist in your query. Is your query being created and executed from your code base, or is it T-SQL stored on the SQL server that is being executed by code?

Comment: The query is created and executed all through the sqlDataSource object in Visual Studio.

Comment: I am not personally familiar with the sqlDataSource object, but if it acts like T-SQL, then you can create your variable as a parameter in your SQL statement and pass the MachineNumber from code as a parameter. If it is just a connection object to connect to your server, you can build your query string out in code as such: `mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [MachineNumber] WHERE [MachineNumber] = " + ComboBox1.SelectedValue;`

Comment: That doesn't work.  I don't believe I can call combobox1 directly inside of the <asp:sqlDataSource object.

Comment: Right off the bat I see two issues with this.  First is that you are using the same value for your table name (in the FROM clause) as you are for a column name (In the WHERE clause.)  Second is that if this SQL statement gets executed as its own batch, you will need to declare a variable `@MachineNumber`.  I think that this is your first error message.  Try hard-coding `@MachineNumber` with a value temporarily to see if that solves it.

Comment: You're missing the point, I have a certain number of tables, and I want this sql query to choose which table based on the combo box selected value.  If I hardcode in which specific table to open, it works fine, but that defeats the entire purpose of doing this.  Does the WHERE clause only work with column names?  Is there some equivalent for table names?

Comment: In SQL, the FROM clause indicates what tables to query.  The WHERE clause tells the query to filter the records in the selected tables.  That is, we only want to return records in our result set where the value in Column_X meets some condition.  So yes, tables in the FROM and Columns in the WHERE.

Comment: [Here is a basic SQL tutorial](http://www.sqlfordummies.com/).

Comment: So is there any way I can have the functionality of the WHERE clause but for table names?  Can I say FROM a certain database WHERE the table name=combobox.selectedvalue?

Comment: But then what are you trying to select?  You select columns from a table (or tables, but we won't discuss Joins yet) and you filter by columns in that table.  A database is basically a collection of tables that are related to each other.  You don't query a database.  You query tables within that database.

Comment: Let me take a step back...  Are you just trying to return **all of the rows** in a table that is specified by the user?  i.e.  Just, "give me all of the data in *that table*?)